# No LazyInitializationException in controller

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, lazy-loading, postgresql-9.4

On my project I'm using Spring Boot with Hibernate 5 and Postgresql 9.4. Now I'm facing a problem. I've got a **@OneToMany** relationship with **LAZY** fetching. When I try to get this collection outside of a transaction, **no exception** is thrown. For me that's not a good behavior - I'm expecting LazyInitializationException which is not thrown. Spring Boot project is new and clean. Everything set to default so far.

Here's my code:

Domain classes:

```
@Entity
public class Company {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="company",orphanRemoval=true,cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Store> stores = new ArrayList<>();

    // getters and setters...
}

@Entity
public class Store {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    @Column(nullable=false)
    private String name;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(nullable = false, name = "company_id")
    private Company company;

    // getters and setters
}
```

Service layer:

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class CompanyService {
    @Autowired
    private CompanyRepository companyRepository;

    public Company getCompany() {
        Company company = companyRepository.findOne(1000L);
        return company;
    }
}
```

Controller layer:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/company")
public class CompanyResource {
    @Autowired
    private CompanyService companyService;

    @GetMapping
    public ResponseEntity<?> getCompany() {
        Company company = companyService.getCompany();
        // HERE I WOULD EXPECT LazyInitializationException
        String storeName = company.getStores().get(0).getName();
        // But storeName is normally filled and resource responds 200
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

application.yml

```
spring:
    datasource:
        driverClassName: org.postgresql.Driver
        url: url_to_database
        username: something
        password: something
    jpa:
        database: POSTGRESQL
        hibernate:
            ddl-auto: create-drop
```

Hibernate **enable_lazy_load_no_trans** property set as default to false. I also tried to enable show-sql and when I debug I can see that hibernate executes SQL selects during **company.getStores().get(0).getName()** execution.
Does anyone know how to pretend this? I want to get a lazy loading exceptions outside of transactions.

Comment: I think you have to delete `@Transactional` on `CompanyService`.

Comment: No, service should be transactional. That's ok. CONTROLLER should not and it actually isn't. But the problem is that even the controller is outside a transaction, hibernate still executes selects and fetches the lazy collections outside the transactions.

Comment: I think if you want to make it throw the exception you have to detach the entity before calling `getName()`. Otherwise it still remembers which `EntityManager` it's came from and uses it to load the data. However the lazy entities still have a mechanism to load themselves from a temporary EntityManager.

Comment: @sovanegger Did you configure OpenEntityManagerInView filter? If so, that might be the reason.